# Show there's no ordered basis $E$ with the following conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

$$T\left( {\matrix{
   x  \cr 
   y  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   2 & 1  \cr 
   3 & 4  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   x  \cr 
   y  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Show that there's no ordered-basis, $E$ such that:

$${\left[ T \right]_E} = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

I assumed that there's such basis (contains two vectors) and applied $T$ on them.
Then, compared $T(v_1) = (1 \space 0)^T$ and $T(v_2) = (0 \space 1)^T$

and I did got a basis answering the conditions above. No contradiction.
What did I miss?

Comment: Note that if there existed such a basis, T would be the indentity operator.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I would like to understand how to solve it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $T(v_1) = (1\ 0)^T$, you're writing the coordinates of the vector $T(v_1)$ in the *standard* basis. But the columns of $[T]_E$ record the coordinates of $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ in the $\{v_1,v_2\}$ basis. That's why your solution to the first equation doesn't work in the problem as stated.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I would like to understand how to solve problems like this one. Do you mind explain?

Comment: I recommend asking a new question. That way lots of people will see it, increasing the chance of someone volunteering their help.

Comment: OK, thank you!!